# Why can't I see my Mongodb collection inside my app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Brand new to mongodb, but I think there must be something very fundamental I'm not getting. If I run the shell and type `db.questions.count()` I get 1,the 1 I created in the shell. But if I do the same thing in my app:

```
...
const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/';
const {MongoClient, ObjectId} = mongo;

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const db = await 
    MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL);

    const Questions = db.questions; 
    console.log(Questions.count()); 
...
```

I get `Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`. Why is this?

For what it's worth, db is defined, and the URL is the same one from the shell. Plus the server starts fine, so I assume that means the mongodb instance is running fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the "mongodb" npm module. It is the official MongoDB client for NodeJs.

```
// Create a Mongo Client Instace to connect to the MongoDB Database
// and perform various functions.
const MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient;
// Store the URL of your MongoDB Server
const mongoURL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
// Stored the name of the Database you wanna connect to.
const dbName = "testdb";

// Create a new Mongo DB client that will connect to the MongoDB Server.
const client = new MongoClient(mongoURL);

// Connect the Client to the MongoDB Server.
client.connect( (err) => {

    // Error handling of some sort.
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log( 'connected!' );

    // Connect to the database you want to manage using the dbName you
    // stored earlier.
    const db = client.db( dbName );

    // Store the name of the collection you want to read from.
    // this can be created above near the dbName.
    const collectionName = "testCol"

    // Connect to the collection that you stored above.
    const collection = db.collection( collectionName );

    // Query the MongoDB database and log the results, if any.
    collection.find({}).toArray( (err, docs) => {
        console.log(docs);
    } );

} )
```

To get rid of that newURLParser error, just use

```
const client = new MongoClient( mongoURL, { useNewUrlParser: true } );
```

instead of

```
const client = new MongoClient(mongoURL);
```

Here's the link to MongoDB NodeJS quickstart. 
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/quick-start/quick-start/